# keyboardview keycodes dont work

Tags: java, android

I just started with Android programming and wanted to create a simple Hangman game with no special gimmicks.
The layout of my app looks like this: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/2cqs6lt3/Unbenannt.PNG
So the main activity contains one ImageView too show the current state of the game, a TextView for displaying the word to guess and at the bottom a keyboardView for the input.

For this keyboard I created a custom keyboard with this keyboard_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<Row
    android:horizontalGap="1%p"
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:verticalGap="0.7%p" >
    <Key
        android:codes="65"
        android:keyLabel="A" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key
        android:codes="66"
        android:keyLabel="B" />
    <Key
        android:codes="67"
        android:keyLabel="C" />
    <Key
        android:codes="68"
        android:keyLabel="D" />
    <Key
        android:codes="69"
        android:keyLabel="E" />
    <Key
        android:codes="70"
        android:keyLabel="F" />
    <Key
        android:codes="71"
        android:keyLabel="G" />
    <Key
        android:codes="72"
        android:keyLabel="H" />
    <Key
        android:codes="73"
        android:keyLabel="I" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row
    android:horizontalGap="1%p"
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:verticalGap="0.7%p" >
    <Key
        android:codes="74"
        android:keyLabel="J" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key
        android:codes="75"
        android:keyLabel="K" />
    <Key
        android:codes="76"
        android:keyLabel="L" />
    <Key
        android:codes="77"
        android:keyLabel="M" />
    <Key
        android:codes="78"
        android:keyLabel="N" />
    <Key
        android:codes="79"
        android:keyLabel="O" />
    <Key
        android:codes="80"
        android:keyLabel="P" />
    <Key
        android:codes="81"
        android:keyLabel="Q" />
    <Key
        android:codes="82"
        android:keyLabel="R" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row
    android:horizontalGap="1%p"
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:verticalGap="0.7%p" >
    <Key
        android:codes="83"
        android:horizontalGap="2.5%p"
        android:keyLabel="S" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key
        android:codes="84"
        android:keyLabel="T" />
    <Key
        android:codes="85"
        android:keyLabel="U" />
    <Key
        android:codes="86"
        android:keyLabel="V" />
    <Key
        android:codes="87"
        android:keyLabel="W" />
    <Key
        android:codes="88"
        android:keyLabel="X" />
    <Key
        android:codes="89"
        android:keyLabel="Y" />
    <Key
        android:codes="90"
        android:keyLabel="Z" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>

keyboard_layout</android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard>
```

and passed it to the keyboardView:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...

private void setKeyboardView() {
    Keyboard keys = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_layout);
    KeyboardView kv = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    kv.setKeyboard(keys);

    kv.setEnabled(true);
    kv.setClickable(true);

    OnKeyboardActionListener listener = new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            tv.setText("" + primaryCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onText(CharSequence text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeDown() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeLeft() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeRight() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void swipeUp() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(listener);
}
```

As you can see I also added an "OnKeyboardActionListener" which just passes the keyCode of the pressed button to the textView.

But when I press a button, the listener just gives a null-reference, regardless of what button I press. (When I don't convert "primaryCode" into a string, the app crashes.)  Besides only the "onPress" method of the "OnKeyboardActionListener" works, when I put the code which is in the onPress method into the onKey or onRelease method nothing happens at all.

And here is the layout xml of my MainActivity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imgView"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/textview_hint"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    />

<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I googled and tried out different settings but nothing helped :(
Does anyone of you can help me with this problem?
And is it generally a good idea to show a keyBoardView permanently like I want to do it in my program?

regards
rakumbo

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
StringBuilder mComposing = new StringBuilder();

String value =   mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
```

**Change here**

```
 @Override 
        public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            tv.setText("" + value);
        }
```

**layout/input.xml**

```
   <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

**Keyboard**

```
 Keyboard keys = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_layout);
    KeyboardView mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.input, null);
            mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            mInputView.setKeyboard(keys);
```